# Django, How to paginate a JsonResponse?

Tags: javascript, django, serialization, pagination

I'm working on a Django and JavaScript project. I'm aware that without JavaScript APIs the pagination would be much easier, but now I'm too far down the rabit hole :)

My **views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def post_list(request):
    posts_list = Post.objects.all()
    posts = [p.serialize() for p in posts_list]

    return JsonResponse(posts, safe=False)
```

My **JavaScript**

```
fetch('/post_list')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(posts => {
      print_post(posts);
    });
```

Then the print_post function does its magic and finishes by appending all posts to a div.

My **HTML**

```
 <div id="to_attach_post_1"></div>
```

So, all posts print nicely in one page. However, if I have hundreds of posts that would not look nice, right? so I have to paginate the posts, lets say every 10 posts, while still sending a JsonResponse with the posts. Does anyone know how to paginate this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/

Comment: Also you might consider using DRF

Comment: @iklinac Thanks for your response. However, the challenge is to paginate with a JsonResonse, not with a return Render as suggested in the Django documentation.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? As I am interested as well.